# Android Studio Button Causing Crash

Tags: java, android, android-studio, button, uibutton

When in the application, I click on a link that should bring me to the sign up page. The application crashes eventually and I receive the following error in the run log.

**Error Message - Updated**

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.alanlyne.tbm, PID: 17423
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.alanlyne.tbm/com.alanlyne.tbm.SignUpActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.Button.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)' on a null object reference
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2913)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3048)
    at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:78)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1808)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
 Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.Button.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)' on a null object reference
    at com.alanlyne.tbm.SignUpActivity.onCreate(SignUpActivity.java:37)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7136)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7127)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1271)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2893)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3048) 
    at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:78) 
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108) 
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1808) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
```

**Code Causing the Error**

```
   package com.alanlyne.tbm;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnCompleteListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task;
import com.google.firebase.auth.AuthResult;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuthException;

public class SignUpActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    public EditText emailId, password;
    Button btnSignUp;
    TextView tvSignIn;
    FirebaseAuth mFirebaseAuth;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mFirebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        emailId = findViewById(R.id.editText);
        password = findViewById(R.id.editText2);
        btnSignUp = findViewById(R.id.button2);
        tvSignIn = findViewById(R.id.textView);
        btnSignUp.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String email = emailId.getText().toString();
                String pwd = password.getText().toString();
                if (email.isEmpty()) {
                    emailId.setError("Please enter email");
                    emailId.requestFocus();
                } else if (pwd.isEmpty()) {
                    password.setError("Please enter password");
                    password.requestFocus();
                } else if (email.isEmpty() && pwd.isEmpty()) {
                    Toast.makeText(SignUpActivity.this, "Fields are empty!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } else if (!(email.isEmpty() && pwd.isEmpty())) {
                    mFirebaseAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, pwd).addOnCompleteListener(SignUpActivity.this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                            if (!task.isSuccessful()) {
                                Toast.makeText(SignUpActivity.this, "Sign Up Unsuccessful, Please Try Again", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            } else {
                                startActivity(new Intent(SignUpActivity.this, HomeActivity.class));
                            }
                        }
                    });
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(SignUpActivity.this, "Error Occurred!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        });

        tvSignIn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent i = new Intent(SignUpActivity.this, loginActivity.class);
                startActivity(i);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

I have also attached the XML page for the sign up activity in case that may be causing an issue.

**XML for Button -  Updated**

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".SignUpActivity">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText"
        android:layout_width="325dp"
        android:layout_height="69dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="85dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="85dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="231dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="85dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="85dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="569dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="Email"
        android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText2"
        android:layout_width="326dp"
        android:layout_height="66dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="85dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="85dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="85dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="85dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="Password"
        android:inputType="textPassword"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.505"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/editText"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.074" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="177dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="177dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="340dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="177dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="177dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="97dp"
        android:text="Already have an account? Sign in here"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/editText2" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/signUp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="66dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="226dp"
        android:text="Sign Up"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/textView"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/editText2" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="176dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="176dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="99dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="178dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="178dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="102dp"
        android:text="Sign Up"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/editText"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

**Code of Previous Activity**

```
package com.alanlyne.tbm;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnCompleteListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task;
import com.google.firebase.auth.AuthResult;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser;

public class loginActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    public EditText emailId, password;
    Button btnSignIn;
    TextView tvSignUp;
    FirebaseAuth mFirebaseAuth;
    private FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener mAuthStateListener;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

        mFirebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        emailId = findViewById(R.id.editText);
        password = findViewById(R.id. editText2);
        btnSignIn = findViewById(R.id.button2);
        tvSignUp = findViewById(R.id.textView);

        mAuthStateListener = new FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAuthStateChanged(@NonNull FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth) {
                FirebaseUser mFirebaseUser = mFirebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
                if(mFirebaseUser != null){
                    Toast.makeText(loginActivity.this, "You are logged in", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    Intent i = new Intent(loginActivity.this, HomeActivity.class);
                    startActivity(i);
                }
                else{
                    Toast.makeText(loginActivity.this, "Please login", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        };
        btnSignIn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                String email = emailId.getText().toString();
                String pwd = password.getText().toString();
                if (email.isEmpty()) {
                    emailId.setError("Please enter email");
                    emailId.requestFocus();
                } else if (pwd.isEmpty()) {
                    password.setError("Please enter password");
                    password.requestFocus();
                } else if (email.isEmpty() && pwd.isEmpty()) {
                    Toast.makeText(loginActivity.this, "Fields are empty!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } else if (!(email.isEmpty() && pwd.isEmpty())) {
                    mFirebaseAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, pwd).addOnCompleteListener(loginActivity.this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                            if(!task.isSuccessful()){
                                Toast.makeText(loginActivity.this, "Login Error, Please Try Again", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }else{
                                Intent intToHome = new Intent(loginActivity.this,HomeActivity.class);
                                startActivity(intToHome);
                            }
                        }
                    });

                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(loginActivity.this, "Error Occurred!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }

            }
        });
        tvSignUp.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intSignUp = new Intent(loginActivity.this, SignUpActivity.class);
                startActivity(intSignUp);
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        mFirebaseAuth.addAuthStateListener(mAuthStateListener);
    }
}
```

**XML of Previous Activity**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".loginActivity">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText"
        android:layout_width="325dp"
        android:layout_height="69dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="85dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="85dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="231dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="85dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="85dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="569dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="Email"
        android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText2"
        android:layout_width="326dp"
        android:layout_height="66dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="85dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="85dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="85dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="85dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="Password"
        android:inputType="textPassword"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.505"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/editText"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.074" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="177dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="177dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="340dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="177dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="177dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="97dp"
        android:text="Not registered? Sign up here"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/editText2" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="66dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="226dp"
        android:hint="Sign in"
        android:text="Sign in"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/textView"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.498"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/editText2"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.384" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="176dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="176dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="99dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="178dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="178dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="102dp"
        android:text="Sign In"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/editText"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: `btnSignUp = findViewById(R.id.button2);` is returning null for some reason, it could be a couple things. Can you first try casting it as a button? `btnSignUp= (Button)findViewById(R.id.button2)`

Comment: No look sadly, Similar error.

Comment: Ok, so in your onCreate, you set the contentView to R.layout.activity_main, do you have another layout? try your signup activity layout instead of main

Comment: Does the app crashes when you click on `btnSignUp` ?

Comment: Just tried it there, still same error but I'd say that was also a factor. I have swapped code over from another activity.

Comment: I updated the error message. @Amine I cant even get to the page, it crashes when trying to access the page

Comment: So the problem isn't in the signUpActivity, can you post the activity and the xml file of the previous activity?

Comment: Add your `SignUpActivity`'s xml. Probably you are using wrong reference of button which is not attached to current layout

Comment: Added previous activity code.

Comment: Added all of `SignUpActivity` xml

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: Not really? The code worked before, it was after I moved it, it caused the issue.

Comment: if it does and I am missing something obvious, I would really appreciate it being pointed out to me.

Comment: When you moved the code, it looks like your references to the old xml ids weren't updated. Your signup button should be R.id.signUp not button2

Comment: @Tyler THANK YOU SO MUCH!!!! I've spent around 4 hours trying to fix this haha

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your reference to `Button` is wrong inside 
`SignUpActivity` Activity.

**Use**

```
btnSignUp = findViewById(R.id.signUp);
```

**Instead** of

```
btnSignUp = findViewById(R.id.button2);
```